# How to create a working .jar for a java project w/ excel input and System.out.print output?

Tags: java, excel, printing, jar

I created this java project that basically gets data from an user determined excel file and uses Syste.out.println() to display the results. It works as I want it to in eclipse, however when I exported is as a .jar file, it doesn't work properly. It prompts for the excel file location to be entered, however, does not display the output, not even an error. I do not know how to do it from the terminal so I'm running it by double-clcking it. Also, I want the user to choose any excel file they want, so what should they write down as the location when prompted to do so? Right now, the excel file is in the same directory as the project. So just the name of the excel file is enough input, but what if it is not in the directory, how do i show it's location then?

Thank you

Comment: _I do not know how to do it from the terminal so I'm running it by double-clcking it._ From the terminal: `java -jar yourJar.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your JAR file the file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF must contain your main class (i.e. the class with the `main()` method), with a line like this:

`Main-Class: mypackage.MyMainClass`

Make sure your settings in Eclipse are generating this line when generating the JAR file.

You can run it from the terminal with `java -jar yourapp.jar` however I presume that you have some extra libraries you need to include in the classpath with the `-cp` switch.

The working directory is normally the directory from where you are running the application. If you want to specify a different path it has to be either relative to that, or absolute.

An absolute path in windows would be something like: "C:\mydatafolder\myexcelsheet.xls"

An absolute path in Unix would be something like: "/home/myaccount/mydatafolder/myexcelsheet.xls"

Comment: However, when I did the java jar myapp.jar, I got an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Can the fact that System.out.print has no median to actually print the string be what causes the double clicking not to work?

Comment: Also, I imported the extra libraries I work with into the program so I'm assuming they are in the jar file?

Comment: No, read the exception. `NoClassDefFoundError: jar`, `ClassNotFoundException: jar`, it means with what you typed it is looking for a class named jar. In fact, you typed `java jar myapp.jar` instead of `java -jar myapp.jar`. Always read the Exception, especially the first line, it tells you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Just importing the classes does not mean they are in the classpath. If they are in the same folder with your myapp.jar then you need to include them in the classpath with something like `java -cp lib1.jar;lib2.jar -jar myapp.jar`. Note that the semicolon between the 2 jar files is valid for Windows, if you're using Linux its colon :

Comment: Ok now I typed java -jar ReliefValve.jar I get Unable to access jarfile ReliefValve.jar. Do I need to go to that directory in the terminal first?

Comment: And what if i'm using a Mac?

Comment: Yes of course you need to go to that directory. You can't expect it to go looking in every directory to find your JAR. MAC is very much like Unix, delimiters are also :. Nothing stops you from trying things out and looking on Google though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read System.in to get the file path, with a function like this:

```
private static String getFilePath () {
    String filePath = null;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please input the path of the file:");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
            filePath = br.readLine();

            File file = new File(filePath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, invalid file path. Please try again.");
            } else {
                return filePath;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Sorry, unexpected error happened, Please try again.");
        }           
    }       
}
```